# 2 wordpress websites on one account?

Tags: php, wordpress

Currently I have one wordpress website installed into the root directory.

How to move it into any inner directory and install another website into the root?

Or maybe will it easier to export data and unistall the old website and install 2 ones? but again How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create new folter in root folder and move all file and folder in created file. After that open database and change url path from wp_option table. After you can create new wp